# Mysql won't start in docker container when mounting /var/lib/mysql to local host volume

Tags: docker

I have the following Dockerfile to create a container running, NGINX & MYSQL. I am trying to mount /var/lib/mysql to the local Docker host, in order to keep MySQL databases after a container is destroyed.

```
    FROM ubuntu:16.04
    MAINTAINER - ******


    ## Install php nginx mysql supervisor ###
    ########################################
    RUN apt-get update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y \
        php-fpm \
        php-cli \
        php-gd  \
        php-mcrypt \
        php-mysql \
        php-curl \
        php-xml \
        php-json \
        nginx \
        curl \
        unzip \
        mysql-server \
        supervisor


    ### Nginx  & PHP-FPM ###
    ########################


    # Remove the default Nginx configuration file
    RUN rm -v /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

    # Copy configuration files from the current directory
    ADD files/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ADD files/php-fpm.conf /etc/php/7.0/fpm/


    ### MYSQL ###
    ############
    ENV ROOT_PWD test

    ### Supervisor.conf ###
######################
ADD files/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf


### Container configuration ###
###############################

EXPOSE 80
VOLUME /DATA
VOLUME /var/lib/mysql

# Set the default command to execute
# when creating a new container
ADD start.sh /
RUN chmod u+x /start.sh
CMD /start.sh
```

**Below is my entry point script start.sh:**

```
#!/bin/sh


# 1.MYSQL SETUP 
#
# ###########

MYSQL_CHARSET=${MYSQL_CHARSET:-"utf8"}
MYSQL_COLLATION=${MYSQL_COLLATION:-"utf8_unicode_ci"}

create_data_dir() {
  mkdir -p /var/lib/mysql
  chmod -R 0700 /var/lib/mysql
  chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
}

create_run_dir() {
  mkdir -p /run/mysqld
  chmod -R 0755 /run/mysqld
  chown -R mysql:root /run/mysqld
}

create_log_dir() {
  mkdir -p /var/log/mysql
  chmod -R 0755 /var/log/mysql
  chown -R mysql:mysql /var/log/mysql
}

mysql_default_install() {
    /usr/bin/mysql_install_db --datadir=/var/lib/mysql
}

create_modx_database() {
   # start mysql server.
    /usr/bin/mysqld_safe >/dev/null 2>&1 &

   # wait for mysql server to start (max 30 seconds).
    timeout=30
    echo -n "Waiting for database server to accept connections"
    while ! /usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root status >/dev/null 2>&1
    do
      timeout=$(($timeout - 1))
      if [ $timeout -eq 0 ]; then
        echo -e "\nCould not connect to database server. Aborting..."
        exit 1
      fi
      echo -n "."
      sleep 1
    done
    echo

    # create database and assign user permissions.
    if [ -n "${DB_NAME}" -a -n "${DB_USER}" -a -n "${DB_PASS}" ]; then
       echo "Creating database \"${DB_NAME}\" and granting access to \"${DB_USER}\" database."
        mysql -uroot  -e  "CREATE DATABASE ${DB_NAME};"
        mysql -uroot  -e  "GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO ${DB_USER}@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '${DB_PASS}';"
        mysql -uroot  -e  "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ${DB_NAME}.* TO ${DB_USER}@localhost;"

    fi 

}

set_mysql_root_pw() {
    # set root password for mysql.
    echo "Setting root password"
    /usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root password "${ROOT_PWD}"

    # shutdown mysql reeady for supervisor to start mysql.
    /usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root --password=${ROOT_PWD} shutdown
}


# 2.NGINX & PHP-FPM 
#
# ################

create_www_dir() {
  # Create LOG directoties for NGINX & PHP-FPM
  echo "Creating www directories"
  mkdir -p /DATA/logs/php-fpm
  mkdir -p /DATA/logs/nginx
  mkdir -p /DATA/www

}

apply_www_permissions(){
  echo "Applying www permissions"
  chown -R www-data:www-data /DATA/www /DATA/logs

}



# Running all script functions
create_data_dir
create_run_dir
create_log_dir
mysql_default_install
create_modx_database
set_mysql_root_pw
create_www_dir
apply_www_permissions

# Start Supervisor 
echo "Starting Supervisor"
/usr/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
```

I can successfully run the container without mounting the /var/lib/mysql folder to local docker host using:

```
docker run  --name modx.test --expose 80  -d -e 'VIRTUAL_HOST=modx.test' -e 'DB_NAME=modx' -e 'DB_USER=modx' -e 'DB_PASS=test' -v /data/sites/test:/DATA  modx
```

If I try and mount /var/lib/mysql using the following:

```
docker run  --name modx.test --expose 80  -d -e 'VIRTUAL_HOST=modx.test' -e 'DB_NAME=modx' -e 'DB_USER=modx' -e 'DB_PASS=test' -v /data/sites/test:/DATA  -v /data/sites/test/mysql:/var/lib/mysql modx
```

the following error occurs: `2017-08-24 07:47:22 [ERROR]   The data directory '/var/lib/mysql' already exist and is not empty.
Waiting for database server to accept connections.............................-e 
Could not connect to database server. Aborting...`

Comment: Why don't you use existing containers from docker hub?

Comment: it's part of a bigger Project to automate the install of MODX CMS, but I have left that out of the code.

Comment: I think it's because I don't declare /var/lib/mysql as a VOLUME, will try that.

Comment: if using VOLUME and not BIND mount it seems to work

Comment: If you really must create your own image, look up on dockerhub's Dockerfiles to get the idea what they are doing and what is the difference by you.

Comment: When you mount the volume, what is there inside the mounted folder in the host? Mysql error says the data folder is not empty, what does it contain?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to resolve the problem. By using `/usr/sbin/mysqld --initialize-insecure --datadir=/var/lib/mysql` but also adding a IF clause to check if the initial databases has already been created.

```
mysql_default_install() {
  if [ ! -d "/var/lib/mysql/mysql" ]; then
      echo "Creating the default database"
      /usr/sbin/mysqld --initialize-insecure --datadir=/var/lib/mysql

  else
      echo "MySQL database already initialiazed"
  fi
}
```

Comment: This looks like a destructive solution. Do you know of one that doesn't involve "initializing" the data directory?

Comment: No, but if you look at the code it first checks to see whether data directory exists.